# Encrypted Git server with Gitolite

Tags: git, encryption, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gitolite

I am considering installing a Git server with Gitolite in AWS, probably the preconfigured [Alestic Git server](http://alestic.com/alestic-git/) of @EricHammond.

However, I want my repositories to be encrypted in the instance. Is it possible? Is it safe? Is [git-encrypt](https://github.com/shadowhand/git-encrypt) a good solution? Is it a better solution to have the instance EBS encrypted?

I want my code to be private. I undestand that the instance is protected from external attacks, but how can it be protected from Amazon's eyes?

Comment: When asking a security question, you need to define your threat model. When you say absolutely private: what does it mean? Does it mean the code stays private if an attacker breaks into your instance? Does it mean it stays private if the attacker breaks into your AWS Account? Your laptop? I'm assuming you mean instance, but you *need* to clarify this.

Comment: 'From Amazons Eyes' is especially problematic. On the one hand you could argue they can't afford to compromise your security intentionally, but on the other hand you make sure no secrets end up leaking through log files or error messages, nor that support personal sees anything may not keep confidential as an individual. This can be as simple and innocent as using password based authentication and having syslog record which usernames failed to login, and you typing your password as the username. For the really paranoid, you could run your own vm inside of an aws vm w/encrypted filesystem etc